# div ultrapassando tamanho dentro de outra div

Tags: html5, css3, twitter-bootstrap, div

Estou trabalhando com o Bootstrap e estou tentando fazer uma 'tabela' com duas colunas. Dentro da coluna da direita quero colocar outra 'tabela' com 4 células, cada uma com imagens de 100x100px. Tudo certo até aí, porém ao redimensionar a página eu gostaria que a altura da coluna da direita acompanhasse a coluna esquerda, o que não está acontecendo.

Segue o código até agora:

**HTML:**

```
  <section>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm left">
          <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>

          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse lorem nulla, feugiat sit amet eros at, fermentum venenatis elit. Nulla at dapibus dolor, ut tincidunt turpis. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Aliquam ut odio diam. Ut mauris orci, commodo quis quam ut, feugiat venenatis neque. Donec consectetur odio in nunc tempus, sed congue erat congue. Nam consectetur ligula quis leo blandit pharetra.
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm right">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm red">
              <img src="https://i.imgur.com/OZ3NldE.png" alt="" class="rounded float-left">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm orange">
              <img src="https://i.imgur.com/OZ3NldE.pngg" alt="" class="rounded float-right">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm green">
              <img src="https://i.imgur.com/OZ3NldE.png" alt="" class="rounded float-left">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm blue">
              <img src="https://i.imgur.com/OZ3NldE.png" alt="" class="rounded float-right">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

  </section>
```

**CSS**

```
div.left {
  background-color: yellow;
}

div.red {
  background-color: #EC4225;
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

div.orange {
  background-color: #F19229;
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

div.green {
  background-color: #378242;
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

div.blue {
  background-color: #0B5790;
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/asfelix/qLf5khep/8/)

Imagem de exemplo do que está acontecendo quando redimensiono:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Qual versão do bootstrap?

Comment: estou usando a versão 4.1

Answer (score 1):

Vc pode criar um *container* com a classe `d-flex`, similar ao que seria uma `.row`, e dentro de as `col-` divididas da forma que deseja, sendo que cada uma tem 50% da largura do pai e 50% da altura. Sendo que a altura do pai é a mesma altura do irmão, que no caso é a `div` com o texto.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o código da imagem acima.

```css
div.red {
  background-color: #EC4225;
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

div.orange {
  background-color: #F19229;
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

div.green {
  background-color: #378242;
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

div.blue {
  background-color: #0B5790;
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<section>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse lorem nulla, feugiat sit amet eros at, fermentum venenatis elit. Nulla at dapibus dolor, ut tincidunt turpis. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Aliquam ut odio diam. Ut mauris orci, commodo quis quam ut, feugiat venenatis neque. Donec consectetur odio in nunc tempus, sed congue erat congue. Nam consectetur ligula quis leo blandit pharetra.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="d-flex h-50 flex-wrap">
            <div class="col-6 red"><img src="https://placecage.com/100/100" alt=""></div>
            <div class="col-6 orange"><img src="https://placecage.com/100/100" alt=""></div>
            <div class="col-6 green"><img src="https://placecage.com/100/100" alt=""></div>
            <div class="col-6 blue"><img src="https://placecage.com/100/100" alt=""></div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```